# How Open B dialog + Close A dialog (help)

Tags: javascript, onclick, dialog

I want to <span onclick="A2A2()"> one click = open dialog A2+ close dialog A1

I want to <span onclick="A3A3()"> one click = open dialog A3+ close dialog A2

`<span onclick="A1A1()">[AAAAAA]</span><dialog id="A1">AAAAAA<span onclick="A2A2()">[BBBBBB]</span><dialog id="A2">BBBBBB<span onclick="A3A3()">[CCCCCC]</span><dialog id="A3">CCCCCC</dialog></dialog></dialog>`

<script>var A1=document.getElementById("A1"); function A1A1() {A1.showModal();}</script>
<script>var A2=document.getElementById("A2"); function A2A2() {A2.showModal();}</script>
<script>var A3=document.getElementById("A3"); function A3A3() {A3.showModal();}</script>

Plz Not Use

"$"
"#"
"%"
"@"

Answer (score 1):

First off, you only need 1 script tag. Secondly you should create functions for each action that you want to do

```
function closeA() {}
function openA() {}
...
```

Then onclick call a function that will in turn call the functions that you need.

```
function closeAOpenB() {
   closeA();
   openB();  
}
```